# insert(std::map<int,struct>) segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, struct, std

I am having a problem with a simple part of my C++ code, here is the issue: I have a pretty big program running some SLAM stuff (which all works perfectly), but I cannot seem to see what is wrong with a small portion of my code. I have a struct called polygon, which is made of up an array of points (which is a different struct), and the number of points in the array.

```
struct point
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    point(float X, float Y, float Z) {x=X; y=Y; z=Z;};
    point() {x=0; y=0; z=0;};
};

struct ray
{
    point R1;
    point R2;
    ray(point r1,point r2) {R1=r1; R2=r2;};
    ray(){R1=point(); R2=point();};
};

struct polygon
{
    point P[];
    int count=0;
    polygon(){};
};
```

When I run the below code I get a segmentation fault, and no error in compilation. What do you think it could be? Is it that I did not define the map `value_type` properly? I just have spent hours trying to fix this without success. Thank-you

```
polygon psdfs;
*psdfs.P = *new point[4];
psdfs.P[0] = point(100,0,100);
psdfs.P[1] = point(-100,0,100);
psdfs.P[2] = point(-100,0,-100);
psdfs.P[3] = point(100,0,-100);
psdfs.count = 4;
polygons->insert(pair<int, polygon>(0,psdfs));
```

`polygons` is a

```
std::map<int, polygon > * polygons;
```

Comment: What do you think the statement `*psdfs.P = *new point[4];` does?

Comment: What kind of language extension allows `point P[];` ? That's... strange

Comment: Did you try with psdfs.P = new point[].

Comment: A segmentation fault generally indicates an attempt to read or write through an invalid pointer, either at the point where the crash occurred or at some earlier point.  At what line are you getting the crash?

Comment: @Andrey It should initialize a new empty array right?

Comment: *psdfs should not work sincères psdfs is not à pointer nor an array. It looks like you have too many indirections

Comment: @simonfrfr, just replace it to `psdfs.P = new point[4]`

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: OH @user3553031 I understand now, Its an invalid pointer problem right?

Comment: @AndreyNasonov that throws an error, that was what I had originally: It throws: `MapBuilder.h:215:11: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘point*’ to ‘point [0]’
   psdfs.P = new point[4];`

Comment: The const in your `operator<` is in the wrong place. You need one after the function definition. Make sure the operators define an appropriate strict weak ordering if you want to use them in maps. And creating a map pointer is strange. You probably shouldn't `new` the map object itself.

Comment: @NeilKirk right now I am referencing an int, so I don't think that those matter right now, I'll remove them since they are a bit distracting.

Comment: Response to edit: did you ever actually allocate a new map or did you just use the pointer thinking one was already there?

Comment: @CrazyEddie You are right, I got so wrapped up in the rest of the code, that I forgot to initialize the map! Thanks, (there are 12 other maps in the program, I just didn't notice!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`point P[]` doesn't do what you think it does.  I'm not entirely sure if it's even valid in that context, but if it is then it's the same as `point * P`.

So at best you essentially have a pointer that needs to be initialized with something.

You might think that `*psdfs.P = *new point[4]` does that but it doesn't.  That's not valid either but if it was it would be a value/copy assignment from an array to an array...but you don't have an array, you have a pointer to who knows what.

What you really want there is `psdfs.P = new point[4]`.

Now all that only speaks to the technical, make it work aspect of your code.  The other issue is that the design of your classes is pretty terrible.  You shouldn't be reaching into classes like that and manipulating them, especially to initialize arrays--something that should be done in a constructor.

I would suggest using `std::vector` instead of allocating with new[].  I would make the variable private and have functions to add points to the polygon.  At the very least I think you should do those two things.

Comment: that throws an error, that was what I had originally: It throws: `MapBuilder.h:215:11: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘point*’ to ‘point [0]’
   psdfs.P = new point[4];`

Comment: Actually it works if I do what you said in the first part, but the issue is that it still throws a seg-fault Thanks!

Comment: You need a proper copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor also.  The array needs to be copied, not just the pointer.  Then each instance needs to delete its own array.  You're really stepping into trouble using raw pointers like this most of the time.  Adding a lot of work that would be better done by a std library class.

Comment: The polygon itself works perfectly from what I've tested, the issues I come across is when I implement the map version because I am dealing with thousands of these polygons. But what I am trying right now is to add just one arbitrary polygon because I found the error to be whenever I access the map of polygons, whether be through an iterator, or just inserting a new polygon in the array.

Comment: Response to edit: did you ever actually allocate a new map or did you just use the pointer thinking one was already there? – Crazy Eddie